# No parameterless constructor defined for type 'ServiceLayer.Automapper.ContactMapper'

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, automapper

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC project.

For some reason breakpoint doesn't go to my controller when I go to the `https://localhost:7204/admin/about/GetAboutList`

I get this error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for type 'ServiceLayer.Automapper.ContactMapper'.
> System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(bool publicOnly, bool wrapExceptions)

Why it's telling me to `ServiceLayer.Automapper.ContactMapper`? No clue...

`Program.cs` file:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qPdd.png)

`AboutMapper.cs`:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qjlj4.png)

`ServiceLayerExtensions.cs`:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UKBY5.png)

`AboutController.cs`:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/epIKt.png)

I if I run project and go to `https://localhost:7204/admin/about/GetAboutList`

I get this error :

> MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for type 'ServiceLayer.Automapper.ContactMapper'.

I tried to breakpoint on

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetAboutList()
```

still it doesn't even go there .... so the problem is with automapper.

Then I created in `AboutController`:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

but I'm still getting the same error:

> An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
> MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for type 'ServiceLayer.Automapper.ContactMapper'.
> System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(bool publicOnly, bool wrapExceptions)

Stack Query Cookies Headers Routing:

> MissingMethodException: No parameterless constructor defined for type 'ServiceLayer.Automapper.ContactMapper'.
> System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceDefaultCtor(bool publicOnly, bool wrapExceptions)
> AutoMapper.MapperConfigurationExpression.AddProfile(Type profileType)
> AutoMapper.MapperConfigurationExpression.AddMapsCore(IEnumerable assembliesToScan)
> AutoMapper.MapperConfigurationExpression.AddMaps(IEnumerable assembliesToScan)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions+<>c__DisplayClass12_0.b__5(MapperConfigurationExpression options)
> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.OptionsFactory.Create(string name)
> Microsoft.Extensions.Options.UnnamedOptionsManager.get_Value()
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions+<>c.b__12_2(IServiceProvider sp)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitRootCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.CreateServiceAccessor(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier)
> System.Collections.Concurrent.ConcurrentDictionary<TKey, TValue>.GetOrAdd(TKey key, Func<TKey, TValue> valueFactory)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider, Type serviceType)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProviderServiceExtensions.GetRequiredService(IServiceProvider provider)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceCollectionExtensions+<>c.b__12_3(IServiceProvider sp)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitDisposeCache(ServiceCallSite transientCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitConstructor(ConstructorCallSite constructorCallSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSiteMain(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngine, RuntimeResolverLock lockType)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.VisitScopeCache(ServiceCallSite callSite, RuntimeResolverContext context)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteVisitor<TArgument, TResult>.VisitCallSite(ServiceCallSite callSite, TArgument argument)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.CallSiteRuntimeResolver.Resolve(ServiceCallSite callSite, ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.DynamicServiceProviderEngine+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.b__0(ServiceProviderEngineScope scope)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceProvider.GetService(ServiceIdentifier serviceIdentifier, ServiceProviderEngineScope serviceProviderEngineScope)
> Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection.ServiceLookup.ServiceProviderEngineScope.GetService(Type serviceType)
> lambda_method8(Closure , IServiceProvider , object[] )
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Controllers.ControllerFactoryProvider+<>c__DisplayClass6_0.g__CreateController|0(ControllerContext controllerContext)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeInnerFilterAsync()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|25_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task lastTask, State next, Scope scope, object state, bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Rethrow(ResourceExecutedContextSealed context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.Next(ref State next, ref Scope scope, ref object state, ref bool isCompleted)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.InvokeFilterPipelineAsync()
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Infrastructure.ResourceInvoker.g__Awaited|17_0(ResourceInvoker invoker, Task task, IDisposable scope)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authorization.AuthorizationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)

I tried to put break point... in
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sk8Di.png)

but it doesn't even go there...

Maybe something is wrong with mapping....

Comment: Please provide your code as text, not screenshots.

Comment: Pls also share your `ServiceLayer.Automapper.ContactMapper`.

Answer (score 1):

Be sure the constructor in `ServiceLayer.Automapper.ContactMapper` is `public` and without any parameters like below:

```
public class ContactMapper : Profile
{

    public ContactMapper()
    {
        CreateMap<Model, ModelDTO>();                      
    }

}
```